# sort function C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault

In this code, for vector size, n >=32767, it gives segmentation fault, but upto 32766, it runs fine. What could be the error? This is full code.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<queue>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100000

bool compare(pair<int,int> p1,pair<int,int> p2) {
    if(p1.second < p2.second)
        return 1;
    else if(p1.second > p2.second)
        return 0;
    if(p1.first <= p2.first)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    freopen("randomin.txt","r",stdin);
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    vector< pair<int,int> > p(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d%d",&p[i].first,&p[i].second);
    **printf("%d\n",(int)p.max_size()); // prints 536870911**
    sort(p.begin(),p.begin()+n,compare);

    //for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        //printf("%d %d\n",p[i].first,p[i].second);
        printf("%.6f\n",(p[n-1].second+p[n-2].second)/(20.0+p[n-1].first+p[n-2].first));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler and OS you are using? Maybe it just has no enough memory?

Comment: I compiled a slightly modified version (I didn't want to enter 35000 numbers from the console :-) ) and it ran fine using VS2008. I guess the problem is somewhere else. Post the code with which the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Its GNU g++ with cygwin running on netbeans. I am using freopen and taking input from file.

Comment: I have included the whole code.

Comment: Never, ever, use `scanf()` to read user input without checking the return value.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In C++, your `compare` predicate must be a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).  In particular, `compare(X,X)`
must return "false" for any X.  In your compare function, if both pairs are identical, you hit the test `(p1.first <= p2.first)` , and return `true`.  Therefore, this `compare` predicate does not impose a strict weak ordering, and the result of passing it to `sort` is undefined.

Comment: Sir: Does that mean that that C++ checks implicitly that if two objects are same, it should return false. But why it was working for n<=32766. Sir:  u r great. You have again helped me solving a problem.

Comment: No deliberate implicit check - just a confused sort algorithm. Different input => differently confused.

Comment: +1 - nicely spotted! @aditya: Remember that STL compare functions are asking "is the first one less than the second" - not "are they equal".

Comment: @Aditya: There are all sorts of reasons a non-strictly-conforming C++ program might work on some inputs, and fail on others.  Consider the case where the library uses one algorithm for large containers (and dumps core if the strict weak ordering is violated), and uses a simpler (and more tolerant) algorithm for smaller values of N.

Comment: Perhaps it goes too deep into recursion (for example, because the faulty comparison function messes up the algorithm's worst case guarantees)? I would also like to point out that std::pair already defines comparison operators (except it uses first as the first criterion).

Comment: This was causing some pretty random segfaults for me. I still can't believe that a bad ordering mechanism can actually corrupt the stack. Great catch, thank you.

Comment: 12 years later this was an issue I was having in my code. Thanks stranger!

Comment: It is related to the segmentation fault, it is the cause of it.

Answer (score 4):

Try using all the values from `n = 32766` up to `32770`. I suspect you'll find that you are experiencing some sort of overflow. This is because 2^15 (32768) is the biggest number that can be represented using 16 bits (assuming you also allow negative numbers). You will have to use a different data type.

**Suggestion:**

Get it to output the vector's maxsize:

```
cout << p.max_size();
```

Let us know what that does. All things being normal, I'd expect it to be in the hundreds of millions (536870911 on my computer). But if it's more like 32768, then that could be the problem.

Comment: How could there be overflow? I am just comparing. There is no arithmetic being performed here.

Comment: Maybe your compiler is setting int to 16 bits ?

Comment: I am sure that on my system, int is 32 bits. I have checked it

Comment: Its GNU g++ on netbeans with cygwin

Comment: Your comparison function should return false on equality, not true.  Not sure why this should cause a segv...

Comment: I'm not saying "It is overflow." But if you try setting n to those few values, and it works up to about 32768, then you can be pretty sure it's some sort of overflow. At least try those values, and if I'm wrong, then awesome, we can rule out one suggestion. I've just added a bit of extra info in my response, try that.

Comment: compare function returns 1 or 0 anyways. How can this generate fault?

Comment: @Smashery: Yes,u r right. it generates fault for 32767. For 32766, it runs fine.
But why this problem has arisen. I m using g++

Comment: @aditya: What does p.max_size() give you?

Comment: aditya, Keith has a point. for n = 350000 where each pair is (0,0) program crashes. after adding if(p1==p2) return 0; it works fine.

Comment: @Smashery:Yes, it gives 536870911. Please suggest a solution

Comment: @aditya: No solution suggestion yet - just trying to gather data to work out what's going wrong. Have you tried Keith's suggestion (above)?

Comment: @Smashery & @Keith: Even If I write a dummy compare function which always return 1 (without any comparison), then also it generates segmentation fault.

Comment: @aditya, always 1 is not not a compararer function.
Compare http://codepad.org/s3vvaai5 [works fine]
and http://codepad.org/sD7kz0b4 [crashes]

Comment: @Keith - Good point, but I'd be surprised if it's the real issue. May scramble the sort results, but a segfault? @aditya - to fix it, in compare, change the <= to <.

Comment: Why it is not a comparer? It just depends on the logic.

Comment: @Steve314: Yes, it worked. I places < instead of <=. But why? please explain in detail in a new answer post.

Comment: @Keith - OK, I think I believe - wierd.

Comment: @aditya, Jim Lewis already explained it. Check source code of sort functions for more details.

Comment: @aditya - that's just Keiths thing done differently. You were violating the expectations that sort has for compare. I'm surprised it segfaults, but...

Comment: Oops - I've been calling maykeye Keith - sorry.

Comment: But why it was working for n<=32766? Where can I get source code of sort function. With .h files its just prototype.

Comment: @Smashery & @Keith & @Steve314 & @Jim Lewis: Thank you all of u for ur great effort for solving this problem.

Comment: @maykeye: when did you become Keith? ;-) @aditya: no worries, mate! Very strange about the 32766 limit

Answer (score 1):

Your overflow is possibly related to the stack overrun due to passing two vectors by value.

**std::vector &vec** - this is how you pass a vector by reference.

Change
`bool compare(pair<int,int> p1,pair<int,int> p2)` to `bool compare(pair<int,int> &p1,pair<int,int> &p2)`

If you think this through, passing by reference will change the size of stack data from size `(2*n*4)*2` bytes to `2x8` byte pointers

For `n == 32767` you are reducing the stack frame by approx `(2*32767*4)*2`

As a rule of thumb, pass by reference unless your design requires otherwise.

Comment: I agree it is not wise to pass these by value. It still probably should not crash just because of this.

Comment: Topic started does not pass vector by value. He passes std::pair, which is 8 bytes, which on x64 platform perfectly fits into CPU register